# white space not working good

Tags: css

hello all I have three `div` and parent div have `white-space:nowrap` when I write large text inside child div all wards is only one line, how can I solve this problem without using `white-space:normal` for child div
here is html

```
<div class="history_slider">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="img/pic/nemiroff.jpg"/>
    <div class="img_text">
which suggests that it formed from nebulous material in space. The hypothesis offers explanations for some of the Solar System's properties, including the nearly circular and coplanar orbits of the planets, and their motion in the same direction as the Sun's rotation. According to the hypothesis, Sun-like stars form over about 100 million years, in massive, grav
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here css

```
.history_slider{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /* outline:1px solid #d6d7db; */
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.history_slider .img{
    margin-left:125px;
    margin-right:125px;
    width:700px;
    height:500px;
    display:inline;
}
.img_text{
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about what you're really after for, but why are you using `display:inline;` and `float` at the same time?

Comment: That is expected behaviour; `white-space: nowrap;` *prevents* text from wrapping lines. Are you relying on `white-space` for your layout?

Comment: I know this, I need help

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve at all, but your structure kind of looks like the [media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/).

Comment: You need to override white-space property for child objects, since they inherit the value from parent object, which has no-wrap value declared

Comment: @val, is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/Lppxm6v0/

Comment: yeas man but when I use `white-space:normal` parents `white-space`
not work good

Comment: If you can tell your goal then it would be better to help

Comment: For parent, I think you sould think alternate of setting white-space. You can only try with float:left for all the children